# Enforce type bound for inferred type parameter in pattern matching

Tags: scala, scala-3

I'm trying to compile the code below which looks correct, although the compiler refuses it. I'm probably doing something wrong or I need to hint the compiler somehow.

```
 sealed trait Foo[A]
 
 case class Bar[A, B <: A]() extends Foo[A]
 
 class Visitor[A](foo: Foo[A]) {
   
   def onBar[B <: A](bar: Bar[A, B]) = ???
   
   def run = foo match
     case b: Bar[A, b] => onBar[b](b)

 }
```

The error is

> Type argument b does not conform to upper bound A

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/FLvBI6WXS1mdoS1FHhir6A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is currently being discussed at [scala/scala3#20040](https://github.com/scala/scala3/issues/20040), and the question's code's validity will be confirmed upon resolution of that report. For the present, there exists two workarounds:

1. If you have control of `Foo` and `Bar`, you can write a `fold` method to circumvent the need for a pattern match:

```scala
sealed trait Foo[A] {
  def fold[R](caseBar: [B <: A] => Bar[A, B] => R): R
}

case class Bar[A, B <: A]() extends Foo[A] {
  override final def fold[R](caseBar: [B <: A] => Bar[A, B] => R) =
    caseBar[B](this)
}

class Visitor[A](foo: Foo[A]) {

  def onBar[B <: A](bar: Bar[A, B]) = ???

  def run = foo.fold([B <: A] => (b: Bar[A, B]) => onBar[B](b))

}
```

2. You can add an outer `match` layer that forces the compiler to remember `B` is related to `A`:

```scala
sealed trait Foo[A]

case class Bar[A, B <: A]() extends Foo[A]

class Visitor[A](foo: Foo[A]) {

  def onBar[B <: A](bar: Bar[A, B]) = ???

  def run = foo match {
    case bar1: Bar[A, ? <: A] =>
      bar1 match {
        case bar2: Bar[A, b] =>
          onBar[b](bar2)
      }
  }

}
```